# Change the Tag positions in SOAP XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I need to take the tag from one position to other.

The request is as follows

```
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <Assertion></Assertion>
        <Security></Security>
    </Header>
</Envelope>
```

But I need an XSLT to put the assertion tag inside security as follows:

```
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <Security>
            <Assertion></Assertion>
        </Security>
    </Header>
</Envelope>
```

I appreciate Your Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Assertion" />
    <xsl:template match="Security">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Assertion"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...produces the desired output when applied to your provided source:

```
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <Security>
            <Assertion></Assertion>
        </Security>
    </Header>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Two comments: use `../Assertion` instead of that absolute expression to be more general; `xsl:copy-of` instruction should be after `xsl:apply-templates` to attributes.

Comment: @Alejandro - Good suggestions. Updated.

Comment: how to do this change when a variable contains value X , if it not X don't do this change.